# ionic platform.is() is not correct after chrome refresh

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I use chrome to debug ionic app. 
The first time ionic app lauches in chrome, the platform.is() is correct, it thinks it runs on desktop. But every time I refresh chrome, the platform.is() thinks it runs on mobile. How to solve this problem?

Comment: what do you mean runs on mobile? can you show the code you are using to do the check?

Comment: I got what you are trying to say:
when you hit F5 with some platform selected in the Inspect Mode, will change the platform to what you have selected.